# Technologies used to create webservices

Tags: web-services

How many types of technologies/frameworks are used to create web services? I know only of Java and .Net frameworks. Are there any other technologies that support creation of web services?

Answer (score 1):

Nearly any technology/language that can be used on a web server can be used to provide a web services API. Take your pick - Perl, Python, Ruby, C, PHP, and so on...

Java and .NET may be among the most popular, but that's more a function of how widespread their usage is in general. If you're building a site using PHP, Python, or Ruby then it makes sense to use that same language and share code between the web site and the web services (authentication, data access, business logic, etc).

Provided the language is available to respond to server requests, it's just a matter of accepting input in an accepted format and supplying the output in an expected format (XML, JSON, etc).

Comment: i didnt get u i am asking about the technology Only .net and java rite supporting the webserivice

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. It sounds to me like you're suggesting that only .NET and Java support building web services. That's not correct, so my response is trying to clarify that and suggest other technologies that may be used. If I've misunderstood your question, let me know or update the question..

Comment: Based on a Google search for "cobol web services", it certainly seems possible to build a web services API using Cobol.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cobol+web+services